# How to print words and the word count

Tags: unix

I am supposed to print both the 6-letter words and how many words there are. the file has it so that the words are on their own line. I'm just learning egrep, so this is what I arrived at. egrep '^.{6}$' nlr.txt| wc -w. It only prints the number of words that have 6 letters in them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Store your result of `egrep` in a variable.  Then `echo $variable | wc -l` to know how many lines that is.  Finally print the content of the variable.

Comment: the question that Im trying to ask is  to write an egrep command that prints all lines that are 6 letter words in the nlr.txt file. Use a pipe and a Bash command to print out how many six letter words are in the file.